# Reset Users Email From Valid to Sandbox Format

Tags: email

I inadvertently updated a couple 100 users emails to their actual, valid email in a sandbox environment when making other updates on certain User fields (Department, Title, etc). Is there any way to reset these emails (without a confirmation email would be great) back to the invalid, sandbox format email, e.g. 'firstname.lastname=domain@example.com'?

Comment: Anonymous apex, Mass Update Anything, SF Data Loader.

Comment: So summary is do manually 1 by 1 or Org Refresh? If there is any other way do put in answers

Answer (score 4):

**Anonymous Apex:**

```
List users = [Select Id, Email From User Where Not Email Like '%=%'];

for (User u : users) {
    //change the email addresses to invalid here
}

update users;
```

As for how to change an email address without notifying them, I think you have to get special permission from SF support to do that.

This will obviously change all email addresses, including whomever is using the Sandbox. So the users that are using the environment would need their valid email replaced, if they need it of course.

Comment: wouldn't this send a confirmation email to the INVALID email, therefore nobody would receive the confirmation, meaning the change would be ignored? I've tried this, and the user receives a "We recently received a request to change your Salesforce account’s email address", but that user is unable to actually initiate and complete the change.

Comment: Ahh you are correct. Suppose I should have tried this out first. The only other way I can think of off the top of my head is to do them individually in the UI and clicking 'Generate new password and notify user immediately'. Or set up a dummy email address to change them all to programatically that you have access to and can then click all the verification links.

Comment: yes, seems like there's no way to do this easily in mass, short of an entire org refresh.